# What cause the Oracle to drop the TNS connection

Tags: oracle, jdbc, coldfusion

We checked the database log there are few drop TNS connections. And at that time, the session utilization is around 90 and current max session utilization is 144 and limit value is 324, the process utilization is around 60 and current max process utilization is 127 and limit value is 200. We checked also the database listener and it is accepting new connection and database working normally. This problem is causing only on the new connections. In other word, all the new connections are not granted. The database refused to grant the new connection about 5-10 minutes and suddenly recovered by itself. The problem does not always be in the exact time and days. What should we do to detect the problem causes. Thanks.

Comment: are you using sql developer?

Comment: Does it refuse new connections with an oracle error or just hangs and never make the new connections?

Comment: What sort of settings are set up for the datasource with regard to max connections, timeouts etc. (under "advanced" settings in the CF Administrator)?